# why does yarn --watch exit (send SIGTERM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, foreman

I have a Docker installation that I would like to start with `docker compose up` (and not have to run 2 extra ttys ) so I added a Procfile.dev looking like this

```
web: bin/rails server -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
js: yarn build_js --watch
css: yarn build_css --watch
```

The output is, however, less than *enjoyable*

```
√ mindling % docker compose up
[+] Running 3/0
 ⠿ Container mindling_redis       Running                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 ⠿ Container mindling_db          Running                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 ⠿ Container mindling_mindling_1  Created                                                                                                                                     0.0s
Attaching to mindling_db, mindling_1, mindling_redis
mindling_1      | 19:54:04 web.1  | started with pid 16
mindling_1      | 19:54:04 js.1   | started with pid 19
mindling_1      | 19:54:04 css.1  | started with pid 22
mindling_1      | 19:54:06 css.1  | yarn run v1.22.17
mindling_1      | 19:54:06 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.17
mindling_1      | 19:54:06 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --outdir=app/assets/builds --watch
mindling_1      | 19:54:06 css.1  | $ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --watch
mindling_1      | 19:54:08 js.1   | Done in 2.02s.
mindling_1      | 19:54:08 js.1   | exited with code 0
mindling_1      | 19:54:08 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
mindling_1      | 19:54:08 web.1  | terminated by SIGTERM
mindling_1      | 19:54:09 css.1  | terminated by SIGTERM
mindling_1 exited with code 0
```

I've tried running a Bash in the application container - and calling the Procfile in a tty by itself looks more or less like this:

```
root@facfb249dc6b:/app# foreman start -f Procfile.dev
20:11:45 web.1  | started with pid 12
20:11:45 js.1   | started with pid 15
20:11:45 css.1  | started with pid 18
20:11:48 css.1  | yarn run v1.22.17
20:11:48 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.17
20:11:48 css.1  | $ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --watch
20:11:49 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --outdir=app/assets/builds --watch
20:11:50 js.1   | [watch] build finished, watching for changes...
20:11:53 web.1  | => Booting Puma
20:11:53 web.1  | => Rails 7.0.0 application starting in development 
20:11:53 web.1  | => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
20:11:57 web.1  | Puma starting in single mode...
20:11:57 web.1  | * Puma version: 5.5.2 (ruby 3.0.3-p157) ("Zawgyi")
20:11:57 web.1  | *  Min threads: 5
20:11:57 web.1  | *  Max threads: 5
20:11:57 web.1  | *  Environment: development
20:11:57 web.1  | *          PID: 22
20:11:57 web.1  | * Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
20:11:57 web.1  | Use Ctrl-C to stop
20:11:58 css.1  | 
20:11:58 css.1  | Rebuilding...
20:11:59 css.1  | Done in 1066ms.
^C20:13:23 system | SIGINT received, starting shutdown
20:13:23 web.1  | - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
20:13:23 web.1  | === puma shutdown: 2021-12-22 20:13:23 +0000 ===
20:13:23 web.1  | - Goodbye!
20:13:23 web.1  | Exiting
20:13:24 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
20:13:25 web.1  | terminated by SIGINT
20:13:25 js.1   | terminated by SIGINT
20:13:25 css.1  | terminated by SIGINT
root@facfb249dc6b:/app#
```

What is going on? It works when doing it 'by hand' but if I let docker-compose *rip* the processes somehow terminates!?!

I have isolated the issue to the `build_css` script in package.json (or at least it does keep going if I comment that line in the Procfile.dev)

---

### All the 'dirty linen'

My package.json looks like this

```
{
...8<...
  "scripts": { 
    "build_js": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --outdir=app/assets/builds",
    "build_css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css" 
  }, 
...8<...
}
```

My containers are exceptionally boring, looking like almost everybody else's:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.3
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs yarn
WORKDIR /app
COPY src/Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY src/Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem install bundler foreman && bundle install
EXPOSE 3000
ENTRYPOINT [ "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

```
version: "3.9"
  db:
    build: mysql
    image: mindling_db
    container_name: mindling_db
    command: [ "--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password" ]
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ~/src/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mindling_development

  mindling:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and finally my entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm -rf /app/tmp/pids/server.pid
foreman start -f Procfile.dev
```

Comment: I think you're right about it having something to do with build_css. I'm running into the same issue running tailwindcss with --watch from a docker-compose command. I was also using foreman where it was failing, but even if I created another container that just runs that process, it fails. Maybe there's some docker security "feature" that is messing with the watcher in tailwind when it's run as a command vs. "by hand" from bash?

Comment: I'm so happy to learn that I'm not the only one - thank you for sharing!

Comment: You should change the question title to be docker specific. This problem also occurs without docker.

Comment: @count0 not sure what you mean? How does changing the question title help if the problem also occurs without docker?

Comment: @wait_die Sorry my suggestion was neither clear nor helpful. What i meant is that the answers and the question are all docker specific, but the title is not. F.e.: my yarn --watch exits because of caching issues, no docker involved. It has also nothing to do with TTY redirection. My solution to this question title would be: run `rails assets:clobber'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Allow me to give credit to they who deserve it!! The correct answer was provided by [earlopain](https://github.com/Earlopain) in [this issue on rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/44048)

It's actually an almost embarrassingly easy fix - once you know it :)

Add tty: true to your docker-compose.yml - like this

```
  mindling:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build: .
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: I had the same issue with esbuild and tailwind at the same time, your answer fixed both problem !
You should mark this answer (even if it's yours) as solved to allow more people to fix their rails on docker problems !

Comment: holy crap, this fixed my day-long issue with **esbuild** not working on my Docker container. Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: Thanks [Earlopain](https://github.com/Earlopain) & @walt_die, you saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Earlopain](https://github.com/Earlopain) & @walt_die, you saved my day. Writing this answer because I had a bit of explanation which didn't fit in the comment.

Just like yours, when trying to run `rails` in `docker` using `docker-compose` the problem I was facing was that `CMD bin/dev` in `dockerfile` was constantly crashing, although it worked when ran manually via bash.

The issue was not with `tailwindcss` but `esbuild` instead. This line `js: yarn build --watch` in `Procfile.dev` was failing because it runs `esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets` under the hood, and as mentioned by [evanw](https://github.com/evanw) in [esbuild issue](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/1848) esbuild exits when stdin is closed.

So, the solution of adding `tty: true` to `docker-compose.yml` as above works.
Alternatively, one can also remove/comment out this line `js: yarn build --watch` from `Procfile.dev` works. But this won't compile the JS changes. So, one can jump into bash of the running container and manually run `yarn build --watch`

Comment: I commented `js` on `Procfile.dev` and starting run manually but it's crash too e kill all container :(